# Is it safe to enable CORS for a Token based webservice?

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am coding a C# WebAPI 2 webservice with Token based authentication from the sample app at this resource: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

I am wanting the webservice to be able to be accessed by users from their own HTML webpages.

Is it safe to enable CORS for all domains for a Local Login webservice that uses Token based authentication?

Comment: More simply put, you are asking, "Is it okay to enable CORS when I want to do CORS?"

Answer (score 1):

There is no other possibility. Otherwise your users always get problems with CORS. I would enable CORS.

Answer (score 0):

"Enable CORS for all domains" would concern me. You should have a list of trusted domains that requests can come from. This is the way it's meant to work.

Comment: If he really knows all domains this would be a great solution, but his question does not sound like he knows all domains.

Comment: I would then say that the answer to his question about it being safe is no, it is not.